# How to customize map style in openmaptiles server

Tags: docker, mapbox, openstreetmap, openmaptiles

I'm trying to apply my custom map style to an evaluation version of `OpenMapTile server` ([klokantech/openmaptiles-server](https://hub.docker.com/r/klokantech/openmaptiles-server/)) on Linux which is running in Docker.

I used the online version of `Maputnik` to edit the map in `OSM-Bright style`. Then I downloaded the modified JSON but I'm not sure how to apply this custom style to the my `OpenMapTile server`.

I logged into the `Linux` in `Docker container` and found the corresponding `style.json` file, but my changes applied will be lost whenver the container is restarted. Could anyone tell what am I missing?

Comment: How can we help you find what's wrong with your code if we can't see your code?

Comment: There is no code. I have a file generated by Maputnik that I need to insert into the running server configuration but don't know how. That is my question.

Answer (score 5):

In the /data/config.json file add your json file:

```
{
  "styles": {
    "standard": [
      "dark-matter",
      "klokantech-basic",
      "osm-bright",
      "positron"
    ],
    "custom": [
      "style.json",
    ....
```

And place that file in /data/styles. You need to restart the container after

Comment: i did the suggested and got the new styles listed on the landing page but when didnt yield any new style maps. All i did was make a copy of the klokantech-basic.GL and changed the color of all water bodies to red color, but no help. what should be done to get the maps with the style. btw, i did commit and restart the container

Comment: Did you add the style.json to /data/styles directory? You have to add it

Comment: i did, only the thumbnail on the dashboard shows the red seas but not the full maps, not sure what the issue is

Comment: @RaveenBeemsingh Did you by any chance manage to resolve this? I'm having the same issue